Debugging logic app standard workflow + local func with inline JavaScript action, fails
I'm developing a logic app standard solution on VS Code for Windows v.193.0. The version of the logic apps standard extension is 4.57.7. I have version 22.8.0 of Node installed.
It has been working great and I've been able to debug by clicking the "Run and Debug" icon from the extensions toolbar, then selecting "Attach to logic app (LogicApp)".
I've just added an action to a workflow for "JavaScriptCode". Now when I click to debug I get the following error:

Worker failed to load function: 'WorkflowNodeWorker' with functionId:
'f199ee64-c633-462d-90b7-e2495038515a'. Result: Failure Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid entry point configuration.
The function entry point must be defined in the format
.    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultMethodInfoLocator.GetMethod(String
pathToAssembly, String entryPoint) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultMethodInfoLocator.cs:line
19    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Definition.GrpcFunctionDefinition..ctor(FunctionLoadRequest
loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Definition\GrpcFunctionDefinition.cs:line
56    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.FunctionLoadRequestHandler(FunctionLoadRequest
request, IFunctionsApplication application, IMethodInfoLocator
methodInfoLocator) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcWorker.cs:line 269 Stack:
at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultMethodInfoLocator.GetMethod(String
pathToAssembly, String entryPoint) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultMethodInfoLocator.cs:line
19    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Definition.GrpcFunctionDefinition..ctor(FunctionLoadRequest
loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Definition\GrpcFunctionDefinition.cs:line
56    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.FunctionLoadRequestHandler(FunctionLoadRequest
request, IFunctionsApplication application, IMethodInfoLocator
methodInfoLocator) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcWorker.cs:line 269. Worker
failed to load package.json: file does not exist Worker process
started and initialized. Worker was unable to load function
ReadQueueSessionMessage: 'Invalid or unexpected token' Worker failed
to load function: 'ReadQueueSessionMessage' with functionId:
'36906878-137e-43f2-b9b9-983ae9eb43c2'. Result: Failure Exception:
Worker was unable to load function ReadQueueSessionMessage: 'Invalid
or unexpected token' Stack:
C:\GitRepos\Acme\Integration\services\process-manager\src\LogicApp\lib\custom\net472\SvcBusQReader.AzFunc.dll:1
MZ? SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1491:20)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1691:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1317:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:12)
at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1339:12)
at Object.apply (C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:51713)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:135:16).

Anyone know a fix for this?

I am able to run it by using below approach:
Versions used:
node version: v20.12.2
dotnet version: 9.0.100-preview.7.24407.12


Using Azure Logic Apps (Standard) v4.57.7.
In Extension settings, i enabled all.
Below are steps to run the Logic app Standard with JavaScript inline and I followed Document:
I have signed up for ngrok and then used the command
ngrok config add-authtoken xxxx

then  ngrok http 7071
Then i have created a logic app with trigger when a http request is received and then inline action with compose showing the output. After Saving then taken url from overview:


Then, I run it from postman. It called the url and my workflow got triggered :


Apologies, my question was a little rushed as I was late leaving for a holiday. It seems this error only presents itself when the logic app contains a workflow that makes use of a local function: please see sample at: https://github.com/RobBowman/la-javascript-error

I have also added this github issue: https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/1187
